# Get value where ID in one table equals to the ID in another table

Tags: sql-server, join

I am stuck on this SQL problem which may be easier than I think. So in a nutshell, how do I go about selecting the cost from the appropriate garage when the `GarageHistID` in the `GarageCosts` table equals to the `ID` in the `GarageHistory` table?

**GarageCosts**

```
GarageID    Cost     Version      GarageHistID
  950       213         1          455
  950       342         3          NULL
```

**GarageHistory**

```
 ID     VendorID      Version       GarageID
454        44           1             NULL
455         2           1             950
456        44           2             NULL
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 VendorID      Cost     Version 
     2          213        1
     44          0         1
     44          0         2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a left join coalescing a null to zero.

```
SELECT 
    gh.VendorID,
    ISNULL(gc.Cost,0) AS Cost,
    gh.Version
FROM GarageHistory gh
LEFT JOIN GarageCost gc
    ON gh.GarageID = gc.GarageID
    AND gh.VersionID = gc.VersionID
```

There is no (specific) need to have bi-directional keys in your 2 tables, but you could use either for the join (along with `VersionID`).

Answer (score 1):

The following query gives the exact results you mentioned in your question. You can use left join to join the two tables based on GarageHistID field in GarageCosts table and ID field in GarageHistory table

```
  SELECT 
    gh.VendorID,
    ISNULL(gc.Cost,0) AS Cost,
    gh.[Version] 
FROM GarageHistory gh
 left JOIN GarageCosts gc
    ON gh.ID = gc.GarageHistID
        order by gc.Cost desc
```